# Detect when WPF textbox has finished rendering after pasting text

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a small program written to manipulate textual data then write it to a text file. A typical workflow is this:

1. Open an Excel file, select and copy the whole worksheet.
2. Paste the data into a multi-line textbox in my WPF app.
3. Choose options, click export, and let it do its thing.

Here's the problem. When pasting a lot of data (600,000 lines etc), it takes a little while till the data actually appears in the textbox even though the paste event happens immediately. I'm assuming that the delay is a rendering issue.

When the paste event fires I pop up a status window alerting the user that pasting has begun.

**I want to know when the paste/redraw has finished so I can close the status window** but have been unable to find any info on the subject.

I'm probably googling the wrong stuff since all I can find is work arounds for forcing a windows to redraw before continuing code execution. This seems like an ugly hack to me. I'd rather simply listen for a "render completed" event. Maybe there isn't anything like that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look here: http://geekswithblogs.net/ilich/archive/2012/10/16/running-code-when-windows-rendering-is-completed.aspx

> WPF is full of surprises. It makes complicated tasks easier, but at
>   the same time overcomplicates easy  task as well. A good example of
>   such overcomplicated things is how to run code when you’re sure that
>   window rendering is completed. Window Loaded event does not always
>   work, because controls might be still rendered. I had this issue
>   working with Infragistics XamDockManager. It continued rendering
>   widgets even when the Window Loaded event had been raised.
>   Unfortunately there is not any “official” solution for this problem.
>
> But there is a trick. You can execute your code asynchronously using
>   Dispatcher class.

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => Trace.WriteLine("DONE!",
"Rendering")), DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle, null);
```

> This code should be added to your Window Loaded event handler. It is
>   executed when all controls inside your window are rendered. Seems to
>   address your issue